# dbForge Studio diagram Automatically add related table to Database Diagram

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, diagram, dbforge

I am working with a very big database with 950 tables.

It's absurd to even try to create the ERM but I am new in this company and I need to understand their relations.

It's a retail company so a lot of the tables are product details and useless.
I have found some of the main tables and I want to find their first relational table and in some cases level 2 related tables.

is there any way to add a table and all of the related table automatically?
I am open to other apps but most of them crash in loading the tables.
for example, you have this option in MySQL workbench but it crashes on loading tables list and I can't even choose a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

1. find the table in a Database Explorer
2. open **Depends On** and **Used By** node for the table
3. select all objects you need in **Depends On** and **Used By** nodes, and drag them to Database Diagram.

Also, you can view data from related tables in a [Master-Detail Browser](https://docs.devart.com/studio-for-mysql/viewing-data-in-master-detail-tables/viewing-data-in-related-tables.html).